# How to load 1587 classes from single file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, class, class-alias

I'm integrating Magento 2 with NetSuite CRM.
I'm following **[this](https://github.com/travisghansen/netsuite-php-toolkit/tree/master/PHPToolkit)** GitHub doc 
I want all of the services provided in there 
There are 3 files 
 1. NSconfig.php 
 2. NSPHPClient.php 
 3. NetSuiteService.php

The third one files contain 1,41,203 line of PHP code with 1587 classes.

How can I use it in Magento 2 and write every class in a single file and load each of them programmatically?

Any idea or suggestion would be great for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just done below thing in magento 2 and got what I wanted

1. NSconfig.php
2. NSPHPClient.php
3. NetSuiteService.php

I just put above core PHP files in app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/Netsuit

Then I created Model app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/Model/NetsuitData.php

With below contents

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\MyModule\Model;
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/Netsuit/NetSuiteService.php';
class NetsuitData
{
}
```

when I want to use all 1587 classes, I just instantiate above class and I'm able to use all the classes of NetSuite.

Thank You!

Comment: It works like a charm!!!

Comment: You saved my day and It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Dont create the files. Use composer install

```
composer require travisghansen/netsuite-php-toolkit
```

Comment: Thank you, Krishnan.
Will it work for all of the NetSuite services?

Comment: Yes you can access classes using namspace

Comment: Can you please share example or documentation for this?

Comment: It is giving me an error

Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class NetSuite\NetSuiteService does not exist

Comment: is ther class NetSuiteService in that module?

Comment: \NetSuite\WebServices\NetSuiteService please try like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70037/discussion-between-bhavin-shah-and-krishnan-daiva).

Answer (score 0):

Split up that file and implement a sane layout in the one class per file paradigm.

Btw. use an autoloader ...

Comment: I've resolved it and got solution please check.

Comment: We do not need to spit anything.

Comment: that's not a solution but a mere workaround around very bad code, sorry

Comment: That is fine. It is correct code. Thank you for trying to help :)